# Can Timestamp datatype insert UTC time rather than the local time(System_time_Zone)

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, timezone, timestamp

Is there a way that Timestamp can insert UTC time rather than the local time(System_time_Zone).

As per MySQL documentation - 
"MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval."

When I insert a now() in a timestamp datatype, the value getting saved is the local time which is the same with Datetime datatype. The date value seems to be static for Datetime but TimeZone keeps updating when Session timezone is updated.

MySQL Workbench 6.3 queries - I am Currently in EDT time zone.

```
desc datedemo ;

--------------------------------------------------
| mydatetime        | 'datetime'              |
--------------------------------------------------
| mytimestamp       |'timestamp'              |
--------------------------------------------------
| utcdate           | datetime                |
--------------------------------------------------

SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;

--------------------------------------------------
| @@global.time_zone|'@@session.time_zone'
--------------------------------------------------
| SYSTEM            | SYSTEM |
--------------------------------------------------

insert into datedemo values (now(), now(),UTC_TIMESTAMP());

select * from datedemo

----------------------------------------------------------------------
| mydatetime         | mytimestamp              | utcdate
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2017-06-21 16:20:28|  2017-06-21 16:20:28     |2017-06-21 20:20:28
----------------------------------------------------------------------

SET  SESSION TIME_ZONE = "+00:00"; // UTC time ZONE

select * from datedemo

----------------------------------------------------------------------
| mydatetime         | mytimestamp              | utcdate
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2017-06-21 16:20:28|  2017-06-21 20:20:28     |2017-06-21 20:20:28
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where is timeStamp datatype saving the UTC time? As per my understanding it is just using the session timeZone and converting the time accordingly, which is done by Datetime also, the only difference being datetime is static but TimeStamp keeps shifting using the client timeZone.

I could be completely wrong but I would greatly appreciate if this question can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

From [the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as `DATETIME`.)

Whatever value you put into a `DATETIME` type will remain exactly how you set it.

The value you put into a `TIMESTAMP` type will be converted when you store it, from the session time zone to UTC.  Then when you read it back it converts from UTC to the session time zone.

The global time zone only defines what the session time zone is set to if you don't set it explicitly during your session.

In general, if you know you want conversions across time zones, then use a `TIMESTAMP` type.  On the other hand, if you want the value to always be exactly what you put in, regardless of session time zone, then use a `DATETIME` type.

It is perfectly valid to create a field like `CreatedUTC` that is always written and read in UTC and is a `DATETIME` type.  However you might instead prefer just `Created` as a `TIMESTAMP`, if you trust the session time zone will be used properly.